# while loop on list with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, grep

I'm trying to run a for loop which will replace strings within files passed as a list.

Example:

```
Filename1

Filename2

File name3

File name4
```

My current code is:

```
for i in `grep -Rl 'OLD' *`; do                                                                                                                 
> perl -pe 's/OLD/NEW/g' -pi "$i"
> done

Can't open File: No such file or directory.
Can't open name3: No such file or directory.
Can't open File: No such file or directory.
Can't open name3: No such file or directory.
Can't open File: No such file or directory.
Can't open name4: No such file or directory.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid word splitting, you can say:

```
grep -Rl 'OLD' * | while read i; do
  perl -pe 's/OLD/NEW/g' -pi "$i";
done
```

or

```
while read i; do
  perl -pe 's/OLD/NEW/g' -pi "$i";
done < <(grep -Rl 'OLD' *)
```

Comment: This will have issues with filenames containing a newline.  (But who puts a newline in a filename?  The same people who put spaces in filenames!)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `xargs` with `sed`

```
grep -Rl 'OLD' * -Z | xargs -0 sed -i 's/OLD/NEW/g'
```

Note the use of `-Z` option of `grep` to terminate output with *null*, compatible with `xargs -0`. This will overcome white space issue in file names.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use find to do that:

```
find -name 'File*' -exec sed -i 's,OLD,NEW,g' {} \;
```